# After Python 3.6.2 Installation Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the python shell error shows when it launched, Please let me know if this causes an issue or how to solve this?

I have installed most recent version of Python 3.6.2 and installed Django later.

```
3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 0, line 21
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 994, in _gcd_import
    return _find_and_load(name, _gcd_import)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 971, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    _call_with_frames_removed(import_, parent)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 994, in _gcd_import
    return _find_and_load(name, _gcd_import)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 971, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    raise ModuleNotFoundError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplesocial'
```

Comment: Install the package `simplesocial` (see last line of the error traceback).

Comment: do I need to install with pip install simplesocial command?

Comment: That's usually the best way!

Comment: I tried to answer but ended in error as below
C:\Windows\System32>pip install simplesocial
Collecting simplesocial
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement simplesocial (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for simplesocial

Comment: This appears to be a django package... see @Cyzanfar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the last error message in the stack trace, You're missing the `simplesocial` module which is a Django package. Install using `pip`:

```
pip install django-simple-social
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, you don't have the module `simplesocial` installed.